# django ModelMultipleChoiceField generate multiple option from an instance

Tags: django, django-forms, jquery-select2

i have been given a project that has a ModelForm like this:

```py
class AddUserToPrivateCourseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = [
            'users',
        ]
```

and users is a Foreignkey relation to user table .it works as expected it generates a select option html

```html
<select>
    <option value="pk1">Name</option>
    <option value="pk2">Name</option>
</select>
```

that are then in the template converted by [select2](https://select2.org) to dynamic search field , which the options are users to be selected By Name for the relevant course 
now i have to add users phone Numbers as a search property in the field.

so i thought of something like the widget generates something like this

```html
<select>
    <option value="pk1">Name</option>
    <option value="pk1">Phone Number</option>
    <option value="pk2">Name</option>
    <option value="pk2">Phone Number</option>
</select>
```

is this possible or i have to come up with something completely different to solve this?

Comment: From a UX point of view, I think this should be split into two fields, with a radio button to select whether to search by name or phone. Just a thought!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching and finding this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4845728/11851550) i came up with this:

```py
class AddUserToPrivateCourseForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = [
            'users',
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['users'].widget.attrs.update({"class": "form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 select2 selectField"})
        additional_options = self.make_option_list(self.fields['users'].choices)
        self.fields['users'].choices = list(self.fields['users'].choices) + additional_options

    def make_option_list(self, choices):
        choice_list = []
        for item in choices:
            user = User.objects.get(pk=item[0])
            choice_list.append((item[0], user.get_mobile()))
        return choice_list
```